# Linked list output NameOfTheList@something

Tags: java, linked-list

every time I try to printout my linked list, the output is TheNameOfMyList@something ... any idea why that's happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: Your question provides zero details, but is it because you're calling `toString()` on a Java Collection rather than iterating through its values and printing them individually?

Comment: Please show the code you use for printing out the value.

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis, I didn't know that. Problem solved.